# With BeautifulSoup How to get content from Meta tag

Tags: python, flask, beautifulsoup

I am working with a Flask api, trying to retrieve e.g. the page description from the meta tag and I can retrieve the full tag, but I only want the contents section.

```
 Html_Content_of_page = requests.get(website).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(Html_Content_of_page, "html5lib")
    print(soup.find("meta", property="og:title"))
```

e.g. when website = 'https://nytimes.com'

this code prints to the terminal/console:

```
<meta content="The New York Times - Breaking News, US News, World News and Videos" data-rh="true" property="og:title"/>
```

Instead, I want only:
`"The New York Times - Breaking News, US News, World News and Videos"`

without the actual tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `soup.find("meta", property="og:title")` would return the element with given name and property. You can use the `element["tag_name"]` to extract the corresponding tag value of "tag_name". Try -

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
Html_Content_of_page = requests.get("https://nytimes.com").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(Html_Content_of_page, "html5lib")
print(soup.find("meta", property="og:title")["content"])
```

outputs -

```
The New York Times - Breaking News, US News, World News and Videos
```

The `element["tag_name"]` raises `KeyError` if `tag_name` does not exist in the `element`. So you can use `soup.find("meta", property="og:title").get('contents')` instead which would return `None` if the `tag_name` does not exist in the element.

Comment: Max. Thanks for taking a look. these are not working unfortunately. I am trying both:         Html_Content_of_page = requests.get(website).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(Html_Content_of_page, "html5lib")
        print(soup.title.text)
        print(soup.find("meta", property="og:title").get('content'))
        print(soup.find("meta", property="og:description")["content"]). Returns The New York Times ...
<meta content="The New York Times ..." data-rh="true" property="og:title"/>
<meta content="Live news.." data-rh="true" property="og:description"/>

Comment: @user2799827 try executing my code as is in a python interpreter - ```>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests
>>> Html_Content_of_page = requests.get("https://nytimes.com").text
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(Html_Content_of_page, "html5lib")
>>> print(soup.find("meta", property="og:title")["content"])
The New York Times - Breaking News, US News, World News and Videos
>>>```

Comment: Nevermind this works. Restarted the server. Not sure why I needed to do that, but your code works!